# How to store Tornado logs to a file?

Tags: python, flask, tornado

I've been facing issues where my server is throwing a 500 if the API isn't accessed for 30 mins at a stretch. To check the problem, I need to keep track of every single API request made. I'm using Tornado in front of Flask. This is my code so far:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from flasky import app
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import FallbackHandler

from tornado.log import enable_pretty_logging
enable_pretty_logging()


tr = WSGIContainer(app)

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r".*", FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=tr)),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.listen(5000)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Whats the most efficient way to store the logs to some file?

I tried doing this but it only works when the process exits with 0:

```
import sys
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
filename = "C:/Source/logs/" + timestr + ".log"

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(filename, "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)

    def flush(self):
        pass

sys.stdout = Logger()
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have used [`enable_pretty_logging`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/log.html#tornado.log.enable_pretty_logging) which is good, and if you might note the documentation says you can pass in a logger.  So what is a logger?  Turns out Python has very extensive support for logging actions through the builtin [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module (which is mentioned in the documentation too).  Generally, you need to set up handlers that write to some specific file, which you can do by

```
handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_filename)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info('foo')
```

This will log all info level entries (or higher) into the file.  These loggers can be gathered by the `logging.getLogger` function, and you can explicitly select these as per the tornado documentation by

```
access_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.access")
app_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.application")
gen_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.general")
```

Simply append your handler to the logger that is generating the messages you want to log to a file.  If it's the `tornado.application` generating the messages you want to see

```
handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_filename)
app_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.application")
enable_pretty_logging()
app_log.addHandler(handler)
```

Or you can also use the builtin tornado options that enable this

```
tornado.options.options['log_file_prefix'].set(log_file_prefix)
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Builtin tornado options totally worked.